# How do i call user control in WPF from main window?

Tags: c#, wpf

lately i'm working on **WPF UserControl**,i'm kind first time using `UserControl` after **WPF** window.
I have created **WPF** Application, it has Window called "`MainWindow`".`MAinWindow` have **Button** named '`Technology`'.
  I have also created `UserControl` named '`TechnologyUserControl`'.I want to show '`TechnologyUserControl`' after clicking on button '`Technology`'.
Can anybody help me ..
 Thanks..

Comment: you wanna show the usercontrol in your mainwindow or in a new window(dialog or not)?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to downvote you or comment: 'What have you tried?', but then again:

You need to instantiate the UserControl, set its DataContext and add it to a parent view. You can do this  either with markup (XAML), or in code.

Answer (score 0):

If your `TechnologyUserControl` is set to **hidden** at first, create a click event on `Technology` and put in there:

```
TechnologyUserControl.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```